# How to display modelforms from dropdown menu django

Tags: javascript, django, drop-down-menu, modelform

In my app I'm trying to implement a feature that helps the user to insert certain "frequent" data.

```
# models.py
class ExamSet(models.Model):
   set = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Exam(models.Model):
    examset = models.ForeignKey(ExamSet)
    value =  models.CharField(max_length=40)

# forms.py
class ExamForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Exam
```

In particular I'd need to:

1) Display a dropdown menu with a queryset of ExamSet (I'm ok with it)

2) Onclick display all the Exam ModelsForms that point at the selected ExamSet

I'm just a beginner of django-javascript templates, help would be very appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [smart_selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects), it allows populating one select with constraint on another's value.

Comment: I found a similar project, it seems promising! http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/